# How to change degree of gradient on mouse movement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I was inspired by this code sinppet from http://codepen.io/andreasstorm/pen/syvoL

HTML -

```
<header>
    <div id="range"></div>
      <div id="currentVal">background-image: linear-gradient( <span id="spanVal">180</span>deg , <span style="color:#4ac1ff">#4ac1ff</span>, <span style="color:#795bb0">#795bb0</span> )</div>
</header>
<div class="gradient"></div>
```

CSS (stylus) -

```
 html
  height 100%

 body
  background-color #292c2f
  font-family monospace
  overflow hidden

 .gradient
  height calc(100% - 70px)
  background-image linear-gradient(180deg,#4ac1ff,#795bb0)
  position absolute
  width 100%

 header
  background #252525
  height 70px
  line-height 70px

 #currentVal
  color #424242
  font-size 14px
  font-weight 800
  padding-left 240px
  span
    color #ccc

 #range
  width 180px
  border 0
  height 4px
  background #424242
  outline none
  position absolute
  left 30px
  top 32px
  .ui-slider-handle
    position absolute
    margin 0px 0 0 -7px
    border-radius 100%
    background white
    border 0
    height 14px
    width 14px
    outline none
    cursor pointer
    &:hover
    &:focus
      transform scale(1.1)
  .ui-slider-range
    background #4ac1ff
```

JavaScript (coffeeScript) -

```
$("#range").slider
  range: "min"
  max: 360
  value: 180
  slide: (e, ui) ->
    $("#spanVal").html ui.value
    bg = "linear-gradient(" + ui.value + "deg,#4ac1ff,#795bb0)"
    $(".gradient").css "background-image", bg
```

In the same way I am trying to implement it on a background of a webpage though I'm not well versed with JavaScript. Is there anyway we could implement the same effect on mouse movement? I mean changing the degree of the gradient along with the position of the cursor on the screen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: do u want to apply it for entire web page ?

Comment: Yes there is anyway to do this in JavaScript. Add a mouseover event to the body. $('body').mouseover(); And calculate the position of the mouse pointer.

Comment: Why not just look at the js that your coffeescript is compiled into?

Comment: this will be helpful http://css-tricks.com/moving-highlight/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/trktqqh6/3/)? Is what you're looking for?

```
$(".gradient").mousemove(function( event ) {
  var w = $(this).width(),
      pct = 360*(+event.pageX)/w,
      bg = "linear-gradient(" + pct + "deg,#4ac1ff,#795bb0)";
      $(".gradient").css("background-image", bg);
});
```

I'm only using the x movement. You can use what you prefer. User moves mouse round the div with class `.gradient`. I just adjust the value to a percentage using the width of the `div` and change the background.

Answer (score 1):

adding x+y and giving random deg

```js
var originalBG = $(".gradient").css("background");

$('.gradient')
  .mousemove(function(e) {

    x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    xy = x + y;
    bgWebKit = "linear-gradient(" + xy + "deg, #4ac1ff, #795bb0)";

    $(this).css({
      'background': bgWebKit
    })
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css({
      background: originalBG
    });
  });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: #292c2f;
  font-family: monospace;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.gradient {
  height: calc(100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg, #4ac1ff, #795bb0);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(270deg, #4ac1ff, #795bb0);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(270deg, #4ac1ff, #795bb0);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(270deg, #4ac1ff, #795bb0);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #4ac1ff, #795bb0);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gradient"></div>
```